# TLSharp error when uploading several files

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, telegram

I'm using TLSharp. My goal is to send files to the user. I created ASP.NET Core Web API service and make HTTP request when I need to send file.

It works well with one file but every time when I get 2 or more requests in a short period of time I get an error:

> System.InvalidOperationException: invalid checksum! skip.

**Controller**:

```
[Route("upload/{driveId}")]
public async Task<ActionResult> Upload(string driveId)
{
    var ms = new MemoryStream();
    var file = service.Files.Get(driveId);
    string filename = file.Execute().Name;
    await file.DownloadAsync(ms);
    ms.Position = 0;
    new FileExtensionContentTypeProvider().TryGetContentType(filename, out var mime);

    var stream = new StreamReader(ms, true);
    await _client.SendFileToBot(filename, mime, stream, driveId);

    return Ok();
}
```

**SendFileToBot method**:

```
public async Task SendFileToBot(string filename, string mime, StreamReader stream)
{
    var found = await client.SearchUserAsync("username", 1);

    //find user
    var userToSend = found.Users
        .Where(x => x.GetType() == typeof(TLUser))
        .Cast<TLUser>()
        .FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == 1234567);

    var fileResult = await client.UploadFile(filename, stream);
    var attr = new TLVector<TLAbsDocumentAttribute>()
    {
        new TLDocumentAttributeFilename { FileName = filename }
    };
    var bot = new TLInputPeerUser() { UserId = userToSend.Id, AccessHash = userToSend.AccessHash.Value };
    await client.SendUploadedDocument(bot, fileResult, "caption", mime, attr);
}
```

When the requests are sent together (or in short period of time), they're sent in a single packet to Telegram server and this error occurs. I need help with this error. I've tried to use Task.Delay but it doesn't help.

How can I handle requests to avoid this error?

Answer (score 1):

According [this](https://github.com/sochix/TLSharp/issues/492) issue, you are not first person who received this error.

Seems like there are something request/response validation issues when using multithreading in TLSharp library.

There is one stable workaround for such type of problems.

#### Make all upload requests synchronous

*Actually, they will be asynchronous, but with one-task-at-one-time access*

This dirty but workable solution can be achieved by creating **task queue**:

```cs
public class TaskQueue
{
    private readonly SemaphoreSlim _semaphoreSlim;

    public TaskQueue()
    {
        _semaphoreSlim = new SemaphoreSlim(1, 1); // Max threads limited to 1.
    }

    public async Task<T> Enqueue<T>(Func<Task<T>> taskGenerator)
    {
        await _semaphoreSlim.WaitAsync();

        try
        {
            return await taskGenerator();
        }
        finally
        {
            _semaphoreSlim.Release();
        }
    }

    public async Task Enqueue(Func<Task> taskGenerator)
    {
        await _semaphoreSlim.WaitAsync();
        try
        {
            await taskGenerator();
        }
        finally
        {
            _semaphoreSlim.Release();
        }
    }
}
```

Now you must register queue as **singleton** in `Startup.cs` file to be sure that your asp.net core application using **one task queue** instance to perform uploading on telegram servers:

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    //...
    services.AddSingleton<TaskQueue>();
    //...
}
```

Next, get your task queue instance in your api controller constructor like:

```cs
private readonly TaskQueue taskQueue;

public MyController(TaskQueue taskQueue)
{
    this.taskQueue = taskQueue
}
```

Then, just use it in all of your api methods:

```cs
// Code from your API method...
await taskQueue.Enqueue(() => client.SendUploadedDocument(bot, fileResult, "caption", mime, attr));
```

This will make all requests to telegram servers through TLSharp library synchronous and prevent multithreading issues like in a question.

---

To be honest, it's just a **workaround**, not **solution** of this problem. I'm sure that [this issue on github about checksum error](https://github.com/sochix/TLSharp/issues/492) must be investigated more detailed and fixed if it possible.

Comment: I have been thinking about this idea. I am going to implement it.